# Windows 10 Settings to switch between maximized and mid sized windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have Windows 10 on my Laptop HP Pavillion G6.

In my system, if a window (let's say Browser window) is maximized and I try to open a program which opens a dialog, when I take my cursor to the dialog window, my dialog goes behind the maximized window ( in this example browser).

I use Tortoise GIT quite frequently and keep Browser window open always. When I try to commit anything, I take my cursor to GIT Commit Dialog but since cursor first goes to browser window, GIT dialog goes behind browser window.

So I want to know which window 10 setting I can change to correct this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "make window under cursor active on hover" type setting in Windows 10.

To disable it:

- Control Panel.
- Ease of Access.
- Change how your mouse works.
- Deselect "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse".
- Click Apply.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem. I tried searching for it on Google but could not find anything.